# Getting an error using inner join

Tags: mysql

My query

```
$con=mysqli_query($sql,"(SELECT  Church Name, Class, Student Name, Mark FROM Church_details INNER JOIN Class_details ON Church_details.Church id=Class_details.Church id GROUP BY Class ORDER BY Student Name)")
```

I'm getting error like this:

```
   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'id=Class_details.Church id GROUP BY Class ORDER BY Student Name)' at line 1
```

Comment: Class_details.Church id <- this is the problem. Those are two words .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  Church Name, Class, Student Name, Mark 
FROM Church_details INNER JOIN Class_details 
ON Church_details.Church id=Class_details.Church id 
GROUP BY Class 
ORDER BY Student Name)")
```

The part

> `ON Church_details.Church id=Class_details.Church id`

You used a space for the Church Id.. Does the table really have a column name with a space. IF It does, you should type it like this

```
Church_details.[Church Id]
```

My bet is that the table's column is Church_Id

Comment: Thank u... i just changed the field name now and tried ... its working

Answer (score 1):

fields can't have spaces in them.  i recommend looking to see if it is maybe Church_id instead of "Church id".  likewise for Student_name

Comment: *"fields can't have spaces in them"* - Not entirely true. It's not good practice but they are allowed. Just as long as they are ticked `\``.